# Extra Header info from Indy message

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm reading email headers from an IMAP account using Indy in Delphi 2007.

The Msg (TidMessage) Date property gives the date and time the email was sent (from the client), I'm trying to get the date and time the email was received by the server by inspecting the ExtraHeaders property, can this be done?

So far I've tried Msg.ExtraHeaders.Values['Received'] and Msg.ExtraHeaders.Text, both of which returned an empty string.

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no header specifically for the purpose of indicating the date/time that an email was received by the server.  If the server wants to create a custom `"X-..."` header for that purpose, that is up to its own descretion.  There is nothing you can do with Indy to force the server to do that.

With that said, all emails have a series of `"Received"` headers to provide a history of what server(s) the email traveled through to get to its destination.  You can extract that data from `TIdMessage.Headers`, such as with `Headers.Extract('Received')` (remember that there can be multiple `"Received"` headers), and then parse it manually as needed.  `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` has no meaning when receiving emails, only when sending them.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I thought this was not going to be as simple as reading 1 property. I'll try the RawHeaders and see if I can extract and parse them to find the final email server. Does the custom X-.... header have a standard name or does the email server choose what to name it (X-Received, X-FinalHop, etc..)?

Comment: `"X-"` is the standard prefix for any user-defined header, eg: `"X-custom-name"`. I mentioned it only as a rare possibility. In actuality, it is doubtful any server defines a custom header for the data you are looking for.

Comment: I can't see RawHeaders anywhere in the TIdMessage class, only Headers, ExtraHeaders and LastGeneratedHeaders?